# Facebook setup with staging and prod version in my Android project

Tags: android, facebook, android-manifest

I have 2 versions of my App defined into Facebook (a prod version and a staging version):

[image]

In the manifest I have this official setup:

```
<!-- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            tools:replace="android:value"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```

In my Gradle:

```
// Facebook app id
        resValue "string", "facebook_app_id", FACEBOOK_APP_ID
        resValue "string", "facebook_app_id_staging", FACEBOOK_APP_ID_STAGING
```

In my Gradle.properties:

```
# Facebook identifier (app ID)
FACEBOOK_APP_ID="XXXXXXXX"
FACEBOOK_APP_ID_STAGING="YYYYYYYY"
```

So how can I switch to facebook App prod <-> staging easily during the project building, because currently it's fixed to always prod version (see the manifest extract).

Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the properties inside the app `build.gradle` file in this way.

```
defaultConfig {
    //this will be valid for release and debug buildTypes
    manifestPlaceholders = [facebook_app_id:"RELEASE_KEY_XXXX"]
    ...
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    staging {
        initWith debug
        manifestPlaceholders = [facebook_app_id:"STAGING_KEY_XXXX"]
    }
}
```

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` then you can use the placeholder:

```
<meta-data
     android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
     tools:replace="android:value"
     android:value="${facebook_app_id}" />
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#build-types) about configuring build variants if you want to perform more advanced configurations